Non-Polynomial Functions which disappear as we take succesive derivatives
I recently learned about the taylor series and how they are computed by assuming that a function is equal to a polynomial expansion with arbitrary constants and then matching up the successive derivatives.
A thought came into my mind whether we could do this with other functions, is it possible to have a non-polynomial function which eventually disappears as we take succesive derivatives of it, so that we could have a form of taylor series not in terms of polynomials but other functions.
Any help on this idea would be highly appreciated!

If the $n$th derivative of a function is identically $0$ then the function is a polynomial of detgree $n-1$.

@EthanBolker is their no other type of function which has this property?

No. Just integrate $n$ times. Each time you get one arbitrary constant of integration.
